# Number of coincident combinations between groups to generate a posterior matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyr, combinatorics

I have a dataframe like **df**:

```
id <- c("A" , "A" , "A" , "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C") 
type <- c(1, 4, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6)
df <- data_frame(id, type)
```

and I want to count the combinations happening in each (**id**).

Afterwards, I want to use the data to generate a symmetric matrix (A):

```
A = matrix(
  # Taking sequence of elements 
  c(NA, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1, 0,0,1, 1, 1, NA, 1,0,2, 2, 0, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1,0,0,1, NA, 0, 1,1,2,1,0, NA),
  # No of rows
  nrow = 6,  
  # No of columns
  ncol = 6,        
  # By default matrices are in column-wise order
  # So this parameter decides how to arrange the matrix
  byrow = TRUE         
)
# Naming rows
rownames(A) = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 5", "Type 6")

# Naming columns
colnames(A) = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 5", "Type 6")

cat("Number of coincidences between Type by id")
print(A)
```

My trial comes in the following way...

```
intermediate_step <- expand.grid(Variety1=unique(df$Type),    # reshape with a symmetric output
                  Variety2=unique(df$Type), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(counts = map2_dbl(Variety1, Variety2, ~length(intersect(df$id[df$Type ==.x], 
                                                     df$id[df$Type ==.y])))) %>% 
  filter(Variety1 != Variety2) 

library(tidyr)
AA <- spread(intermediate_step, Variety2, counts)
```

...However, two **BIG PROBLEMS** arise:

1. intermediate_step is **not computing the count correctly**.
2. this method is computationally super expensive. For this toy example, it works. For my real data (93k entries), **RStudio aborts session**.

... **POSSIBLE SOLUTION TO THE SECOND PROBLEM** ...

- To create a `loop' that works in the following way. It takes the first element of the variable **Type** (e.g. 1) and eliminates all **id** not having (1), e.g. (C). Then, you create a more small matrix with the info coming from the other two id's (e.g. 1, and 2). Then, the algorithm should repeat this step for all the "Type" elements that have not been selected so far.

Any clue on how to perform the analysis in a more computationally and efficient way or on how to apply my proposed solution?

Thank you :)

Comment: can you explain how group4-group1 = 2? group1-group2=0?

Comment: I have modified the variable names to avoid misleading. The intuition goes like this. Every individual (id) has some types of fruit (type). It means that some fruit are eaten combined. My final goal is to create a matrix that tells me how many times each combination of fruits is eaten together. Following this logic, Type 4 and Type 1 are eaten together by two different individuals (A, B). In the same manner, Type 1 and Type 2 of fruits are never consumed together. Hope it is clearer now. Thank you!

Comment: How many different unique values of `type` do you have in your real data?

Comment: There individual A never ate type 4 since there is no type 4 in id A. Either your matrix is incorrect or your data is incorrect

Comment: @KU99 Thanks for the correction. Now the typo is corrected

Comment: @DaveArmstrong 30k

Comment: Seems like you want to do market basket analysis (93K transactions against 30K products). The `arules` package in R is designed for this. Suggest you start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your data is incorrect:

With the correct data - ie row 2 column 2 should be 4 and not 2 `df[2,2 <- 4`, you could do:

```
`diag<-`(crossprod(table(df)), NA)

    type
type  1  2  3  4  5  6
   1 NA  0  1  2  1  1
   2  0 NA  1  0  0  1
   3  1  1 NA  1  0  2
   4  2  0  1 NA  1  1
   5  1  0  0  1 NA  0
   6  1  1  2  1  0 NA
```

Comment: Your code works, but my RStudio session aborts before finishing the run. Do you have any proposal to iteratively run the code for each Type, as proposed in "**... POSSIBLE SOLUTION TO THE SECOND PROBLEM ...**"?

Comment: @vog seems you have a very large matrix, which cannot be sored in memory. Best thing to do is use a sparse matrix.